# Duplicate content tabs and page pagination

Tags: seo, google-search-console, duplicate-content

These tabs are being marked as duplicate content on our website although we don't have tabs on the specific webpage

[image: Duplicate tabs]

Also, there are post pages where we see the page count being marked as duplicate content

[image]

How can this be fixed and is this even an issue?

Comment: What happens if you append those query strings? Does the page work? Do you possibly have links to those URLs?

Comment: yes the pages exist and they all lead to the original category page , regardless of the query strings

Comment: One question: do you have the redirections well defined? For example: http to https, www to non-www, redirecting the trailing slashes, etc.